# Custom Button Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, button

I am new to unity. I need help on creating a button with corner radius, gradient, outer shadow and inner shadow. Two shadows in both other and inner.

Check the image below.

[image: Button default state]

[image: Button Pressed]

Answer (score 0):

404 feature not found

Unity does not have the features to add these things built in. You can however make them with a shader and apply it to various buttons and change the properties to change the result. Shaders are definitely more intermediate to advanced to use and can be time-consuming. I'm not sure where you are on your journey so I'll include workarounds.

Workaround 1:

It seems like you use photoshop, make the images how you want in photoshop or adobe xd and export them as svg or images to Unity. To use SVG you have to import the vector package Window -> Package Manager -> Vector Graphics.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0/manual/index.html

Workaround 2:

Some people have made things like this as a package and put their work for sale on the asset store. Check out the unity asset store and see if you can find what you are looking for.

https://assetstore.unity.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any idea on "Gradient" and "Radius".

Comment: not by default there is this youtube video which does a different workaround, if you want to do shaders gradient would be a good starting point https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FzHONutd6c